# Android multi module development: How to get the names of the modules in android project/ android library?

Tags: android, gradle, multi-module, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have searched a bit in stackoverflow but cannot find answer. I am not sure if the similar question is asked before or not, please vote to close this question if you found similar questions.

I am implementing a side project which is using multi module development. However, I would like to create some dynamic tasks in CI which based on the module name. However, i dunno how to detected the loaded module names based on the following scope:

1. All the modules (including submodules) in the root project
2. The modules included under specific module

For Example:

```
Root Project

-> Feature

   -> Feature A (has core dependency)
   
   -> Feature B

-> Core
```

Currently I am using Regex `'(.+)'` to match the pattern in `settings.gradle.kts` to know the modules in the root project but it is an ugly solution and it cannot check the modules under `Feature A`

Appreciate any advice or comment